# Spring Security Error Pages using Forward

Tags: spring, security

I want to display a custom error page on authentication denial (I am using a pre-authenticated secnario) and also access denial from Spring Security 3.0.X

Understand we can use the following to perform this:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/error.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>
```

but doing this results in a redirect and not a forward to the error page. Anyway to perform forward to an error page (so that we can set some attributes in the request)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my `security-context.xml`, for authentication failure I do like this (pay attention to the `authentication-failure-url` attribute):

```
    <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"
        default-target-url="/mvc/home"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
```

And for access denied I use this:

```
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/auth/access-denied"/>
```

Both tags inside `<security:http use-expressions="true">`. For me works like a charm, I don't know why you are trying to configure it in the way you are doing when Spring provides such nice tags easy to use.

I don't know if it answers your question, I hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Using the configuration provided above, means that you are using the default authentication failure handler ([SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html)) at the background. You can change the default behavior (which as default performs a redirect when a failed authentication is produced) by changing the attribute `forwardToDestination` value. This is what SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler does:

```
/**
 * Performs the redirect or forward to the {@code defaultFailureUrl} if set, otherwise returns a 401 error code.
 * <p>
 * If redirecting or forwarding, {@code saveException} will be called to cache the exception for use in
 * the target view.
 */
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (defaultFailureUrl == null) {
        logger.debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error");

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    } else {
        saveException(request, exception);

        if (forwardToDestination) {
            logger.debug("Forwarding to " + defaultFailureUrl);

            request.getRequestDispatcher(defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            logger.debug("Redirecting to " + defaultFailureUrl);
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, defaultFailureUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess that I you declare your `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` in your `security-context.xml` and set the mentioned property value using the `setUseForward(boolean forwardToDestination)` method it should work. Could be something like:

```
<bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true">
</bean>
```

And then:

```
    <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        default-target-url="/mvc/home"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
```

Good luck.

Comment: Understand....this performs a redirect and the user is redirected to the error page....is there anyway to perform a forward to an error page?

Comment: Well I think I have a better solution which doesn't requires a custom  authentication failure handler, I will edit my post in few minutes.

Comment: I have edited my post with additional content, I hope it is what you are looking for and I hope it works too, of course.